# How to update/add buttons once instantiated datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am new to JavaScript and I lack knowledge javascript objects.
I would like to know how I can add the extension of the datatable 1.10 button once created .

My code is:

```
var table;
$('#MyDiv').DataTable({someCode;});
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.ok = {
    text: 'OK',
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
        console.log("Hi");
    }
};
table = $('#MyDiv').DataTable();
//!Here I want to add my button in table var!
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a curly brace at the end of your definition of the ok button. Not sure if that's part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, there is not a problem of syntax.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

The easiest way to do it (in my opinion) is to use the option form of the button declaration, instead of the function form you are attempting to use here. In your case, that would look something like this:

```
table = $('#MyDiv').DataTable({
    /*Other DataTables config options go here*/
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'OK',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                console.log("Hi");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

This can be found in the [DataTables examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html), which is a great source for DataTables information.

## Option 2

If instead you wish to keep using the function notation, then you would simply have to add a button declaration to the options instead of the whole action/text block that is there in the above example. See below:

```
var table;
//You should not have 2 .DataTable() calls, so I removed this one
//Move any other options you had to the other call below
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.ok = {
    text: 'OK',
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
        console.log("Hi");
    }
};
table = $('#MyDiv').DataTable({
    /*Other DataTables config options go here*/
    buttons: [
        'ok'
    ]
});
```

Either way should work, it just depends on how you prefer to organize your code.

I'd also refer you to the [custom buttons documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom) on the DataTables website to get more information or to see where I got these code blocks from.

Comment: It's not a option because you are creating datatable together with the button, and I want create datatable and in another part of code add/update the buttons.

Comment: Why do you want to add the buttons somewhere other than in the DataTables initialization? You are using the DataTables button function, so the button is going to have to be attached to the DataTable. If you don't want to do that you'll have to add a standard JS button instead.